# Why does t.GetProperty always return null?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, path

I'm coding an app using Visual Studio and Xamarin in C#, and I'd like the user to be able to take a photo and save it in his phone to later be retrieved within the app. To do this, I need to start by saving the photo in the phone. My photos are of type FileResult and I put all the photos in a list and save the list thanks to this block of code:

```
public static List<FileResult> SavedListPhoto
    {
    get
    {
        var savedList = Deserialize<List<FileResult>>(Preferences.Get(nameof(SavedListPhoto), null));
        Console.WriteLine(savedList);
        return savedList ?? new List<FileResult>();
    }
    set
    {
        var serializedList = Serialize(value);
        Preferences.Set(nameof(SavedListPhoto), serializedList);
        Console.WriteLine(nameof(SavedListPhoto));
    }
}

static T Deserialize<T>(string serializedObject) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serializedObject);
static string Serialize<T>(T objectToSerialize) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToSerialize);
```

Now that the list is saved in the phone, I'd like to be able to access the list and the elements inside it, as well as modify it. I'm using this block of code to accomplish it:

```
private List<FileResult> GetList(object instance, string path)
    {
        var pp = path.Split('/');
        Type t = instance.GetType();
        foreach( var prop in pp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(prop);
            PropertyInfo propInfo = t.GetProperty(prop);
            Console.WriteLine(propInfo);
            if (propInfo != null)
            {
                instance = propInfo.GetValue(instance, null);
                t = instance.GetType();
            }
            else throw new ArgumentException("Properties path is not correct");
        }
        return (List<FileResult>)instance;
    }
```

However, whatever I do, the ArgumentException gets thrown. Obviously, it's because propInfo is always null, but I don't understand why. The instance I'm giving is the list itself, and the path I'm giving is the following:
/data/user/0/com.companyname.app1/cache/2203693cc04e0be7f4f024d5f9499e13/9fe8dae02ada45a5bb9eba67d39f7d06/8907af5726ff404fadb415261a7dc71e.jpg, which is the path that I get from the following block of code (after being modified so I get only the path above):

```
Preferences.Get("SavedListPhoto", "false")
```

I've looked but I found no problems which related exactly to what I have. If someone could help me it would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I'm really confused why you think the path components of a filename will represent C# properties on a class.

Comment: Can you explain what led you to believe that reflection was the appropriate tool to use in this situation?

Comment: yeah, I have no idea what purpose `GetList` serves.  You are serializing and deserializing a `List<FileResult>`, why is that not enough?

Comment: it's null because it's not existed on the instance type (of course as public). It's just simply like that.

Comment: @KirkWoll it was a bit of code I found online while researching how to access the list, I tried it out and thought it would work, obviously not